# How to execute outside binaries when the default shell is not a common shell(e.g. dash, bash)?

Tags: c, shell, binaryfiles, c11

We can use `system` from stdlib.h in C to execute shell commands.
But, when the default shell is not dash or bash, it is an unusual shell(such as IPython), try to execute `system("clear")` (or other commands) will get a message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e0829c73c68a> in <module>
----> 1 clear

NameError: name 'clear' is not defined
```

No matter what the default shell is, can I use a C command to execute outside binary directly? If so, what should I do?

Comment: A command like `clear` is usually an alias to echo the VT100 escape sequence to clear the terminal.

Comment: As for actual programs, if you have a path to it then you can execute it. If allowed by the "shell" you use. Try e.g. `system('/bin/ls')`